# "Mount" network share as a volume via SSH?

Tags: ssh, network, mount

There is a remote server that I can connect to only via SSH, and storage space have been allocated for me in that server.

Is there a software that lets me "mount" a network share via SSH so that I can use it as if it is a local folder?

I strongly prefer cross-platform and Free (as in Freedom) solutions, but anything you can think of I'd love to know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use HomeBrew to install fuse4x and sshfs

The commands to install are:

```
brew install sshfs
```

when you run it, it gives two other commands that I needed to run in order to install the fuse4x kernel extension. Run them.

Then, to mount the ssh filesystem

```
mkdir ~/mymountdir
sshfs username@hostname:/home/thedir ~/mymountdir
```

it will ask you for your password.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since I already have MacPorts setup I discovered it has sshfs, too.

Comment: You actually don't need MacPorts or HomeBrew at all to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but for what it's worth, the `man` page for the Unix `mount` command lists that you can connect to remote systems:

```
The mount command calls the mount(2) system call to prepare and graft a
special device or the remote node (rhost:path) on to the file system tree
at the point node.  If either special or node are not provided, the
appropriate information is obtained via the getfsent(3) library routines.
```